# Elixir - Cross cutting concerns

Tags: elixir

What is the way execute some cross cutting concern in Elixir? Say I want to check if a user has unsubscribed to emails - would it be possible to do so before any of the email sending functions get executed? Can't find anything in the Elixir docs that talk about interleaving other functions...much like the before_filter in rails but in standalone Elixir apps. There could be multiple emails being sent - notifications, marketing, transactional etc. Adding each of unsubscribed? checks manually to each of those functions is too imperative. Is there a better way in Elixir?

Comment: That's only my opinion but I think you could just write a special module that has a function that, let's say accepts a user, checks if he has subscriptions and if he does, sends the email. Then you could just use this module wherever you need it. It would be more explicit this way and won't leave you with some callback magic.

Comment: @JustMichael - Isn't that repetitive? I am thinking a module as well, but since every function in that email module needs to do the same thing, checking the same thing in every function isn't keeping with the DRY principle. Also, I am looking at different alternatives Elixir offers while trying to learn the language

Comment: The DRY principle isn't a law--just a good guideline.  Sometimes it just isn't possible to avoid repetition.  While not repeating code is a great goal, readable and maintainable code is also important.  Besides, how do you think AOP accomplishes this?  Do you think they don't repeat code to do this?  It's just hidden from view.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - AOP doesn't repeat code. It introduces a transparent proxy which has the code you wrote do something. Example check user is authenticated what have you. Thats not code repetition. Yes, like anything, a balanced approach is required to callbacks to not make it too confusing that the author of the code forgets it later

Comment: Yes @sat it does repeat code. Look up aspect weavers.  It simply doesn't show the redundant code to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, using `before_filter` actually leads to bad design. I know it's easier to code that way, but after a while, your codebase grows, you add more logic in those callbacks and you start to loose control over them.

You can do the same thing without callbacks, using simple functions, and keep control in an imperative way (way easier to reason about and debug).

Let's say you have a module that has multiple emailing functions

```
defmodule Mailer do
  def send_email1(params) do
    # do work
  end

  def send_email2(params) do
  end

  # ...
end
```

Instead of adding a `before_filter` of some sort you can simply add the code to each of those functions right? That's simple and easy to understand what's going on.

```
defmodule Mailer do
  def send_email1(params) do
    if can_send?(params) do
      # do work
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Now you notice you have duplicated logic. Well... You can move the check logic to a newer function and at least remove the `if` from each of those functions. But you could also create a new abstraction and keep the shared logic there.

```
defmodule Mailer do
  def send_email(email_name, params) do
    if can_send?(params) do
      do_send_email(email_name, params)
    end
  end

  defp do_send_email("email1", params) do
    # do work
  end
  # ...
end
```

This is way simpler code than any alternative with callbacks. You keep control of it. And it's easy to add or change the shared logic, and add conditional logic to it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Elixir's [module attributes](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html) to kick off a chain of tail-call optimized function calls. This makes it easy to declare your callbacks all in one place.

```
defmodule MyMod do

  @before_filter [:check_email]

  def check_email(1), do: true
  def check_email(state), do: false

  def save(state) do
    save(state, @before_filter)
  end

  defp save(state, []) do
    # do actual save
    {:ok, state}
  end

  defp save(state, [callback|tail]) do
    if :erlang.apply(__MODULE__, callback, [state]) do
      save(state, tail)
    else
      {:error, callback, state}
    end
  end
end
```